# How to set client 'header' and 'params' values for a HTTP GET request and read those in the service server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-3, httpwebrequest

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to set `header` and `params` values for a HTTP GET request of a *client* server. Then, on the other side, I would like to read those on the *service* server.

What I do in the *client* is:

```
host = "http://<site_name>.com"
path = "/users/1.json"
query_params = ["username=test_username", "password=test_psw"].join("&")

uri = URI.parse("#{host}#{path}?#{query_params}")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.start do
  @response_test = JSON(http.get("#{host}#{path}").body)["user"]
end
```

What I do in the *service* is:

```
...
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {
    render :json => @user.to_json
    if ( params["username"] == "test_username" && password == test_psw )
      render :json => @user.to_json
    else
      render :text => "Bad request"
    end
  }
end
```

All above code doesn't work correctly: making the HTTP GET request I get always a `706: unexpected token at 'Bad request'`.

(1) **How set correctly the `header` in the *client*? In the example above, are `params` correctly set?**

(2) **How to read properly `header` and `params` values in the *server?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting the "706: unexpected token at 'Bad request'" error on the client side after attempting to parse the response?  If so I would guess this is because your client appears to be expecting a JSON response, and you're sending the unquoted raw text "Bad request", which does not parse as valid JSON.  Try `render :json => "Bad request".to_json`

Any parameters passed in a GET querystring or form POST will be in the `params` hash.

In answer to your questions:

1) You can see your params by putting `puts "params: #{params.inspect}"` inside your controller action.

2) Headers are available in the `request.headers` hash: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers

Here's how to set headers in a Net::HTTP request:

```
url = URI.parse("http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp")

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
req.add_field("X-Forwarded-For", "0.0.0.0")

res = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start do |http|
  http.request(req)
end
```

Comment: How can I render a JSON response with some text explaining the error type instead of the raw text "Bad request"? (1) How set correctly the header in the client?

Comment: Added sample of rendering "Bad request" to json.  What header are you trying to set?  Why do you need this header?

Comment: I tryed 'render :json => "Bad request".to_json' but it didn't work. I need header just to put in that a string value for some internal handling.

Comment: Added "set header" link.  Hard to say why your code is erroring without a full working sample.  Can you post a whole working (albeit failing) test to http://pastie.org or http://gist.github.com ?